# How can I clarify/improve a question of mine that was closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

So I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309354/fastest-php-memory-cache-hashtable) earlier today and it became flamewars and got closed by some older members. I just logged in now after some 6 hours and would like to further specify what I wanted to ask.

Should I edit and reopen the existing question or open a new one and clarify my question from the bottom up?

Comment: It's a little open ended as it stands, as the commenters pointed out.

Comment: Yes I know, I was at work when I posted and didn't take the time to clearly specify certain factors that could clearly be important for a clear answer. I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best thing to do (or, what I would do) would be to edit the question then flag the post for moderator attention and request re-opening. (To flag a question, click the "flag" text underneath the tags).

Comment: OK, I thought the flag button was more like to report spam and such... but if it's ok to use it this way I suppose that makes sense.

Comment: the flagging reason "because it needs ♦ moderator attention" > "other" is fine for drawing mod attention for non spam/minor issues.